# jQuery Sortable Items Float Right Sorting Not smooth Issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

jQuery Sortable dragging is not working smooth when items are float right. I try to fix it without success and I don't understand why it is an issue.

To reproduce and understand the issue, you need to try dragging the items and you will see that sometimes you like to place an item at a place and the placeholder is stays at another place. see the attached image to understand better.

[image]

When removing the `float:right` property it will work good.

Note: Its a little hard to understand the issue, I reproduce it on jsfiddle but you need to play with it to understand it

https://jsfiddle.net/royshoa/4Lprn9bs/72

I will be happy to get some answers for that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that the float to right inside the `#sortable` is messing up the behavior of `jquery-ui-sortable`.

to remain your reverse order (3,2,1) AND align it to the right AND keep the desired functionality working as you described:

- take out the `float:right` from `#sortable` and place it at the
  parent `.example-box`: now the parent's container floats to the
  right, but it does not affect `#sortable`
- to get the reverse 3, 2, 1 order, you only have to reverse the
  elements order within your jQuery code using [get().reverse()](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get) . Doing so the order is now not
  influencing the `jquery-ui-sortable` anymore as no further `float:right` is used

html:

```
<div class="example-box">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.example-box {
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  float: right;
}

#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sortable li {
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#sortable li {}

.draggable-placeholder {
  border: 2px dashed #D9D9D9 !important;
  background-color: #F7F7F7 !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('#sortable').sortable({
    opacity: 0.8,
    revert: true,
    forceHelperSize: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    placeholder: 'draggable-placeholder',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    axis: 'x'
  });

  var list = $('ul#sortable');
  var listItems = list.children('#sortable>li');
  list.append(listItems.get().reverse());

});
```

here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n7b9wezj/3/

note: I've set `axis:x`, because it shows the functionality nicer, but you don't need to set it. The blue border is only to illustrate the position of the div...

**edit to reflect on comments**
here is another example using flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/y9qd08bn/1/
I've set the width to 90%, so it looks better in the fiddle, but you can use it with 100%.

Comment: You solution is working good, I have an issue with it because at my case I can't float right the UL because I need it to be width 100% and at that case the items is still on the left (I try to use flex-box to move them but the dragging not working well). If you can fix it directly from the JavaScript as a patch it will be grate.

Comment: Also when I add the float right to the UL tag from some reason the Helper display around 100px left to the cursor when I start dragging, I didn't reproduce it at jsfiddle but at my side its happen, can you think why? (I can't attache a screenshot at the comment)

Comment: I've updated the answer, adding an example using flexbox